# How do I add pixels to a specific character?

Tags: starbound

Starbound worlds looks pretty amazing and it's time to build up something really big.

Can you, please, guide me how to **add pixels to a specific character**? Is there any way to achieve that with a command in-game or via any characters-related config files.

Any specific doc reference will be appreciated!

---

**Update**

Considering answer. I'm wondering if there a PC tool to edit character file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without installing any mods or other utilities:

First activate admin mode by running:

```
/admin
```

Then we spawn in the item for pixels (called `money` in the code). You can replace `x` in this command with the amount you want.

```
/spawnitem money x
```

The pixels will spawn in the world at your cursor. If you get a Perfectly Generic Item instead, check wether you entered the command correctly. If it errors, check the command or lower `x`.

Lastly, to leave admin mode:

```
/admin
```

This won't work in multiplayer unless you are the host.

EDIT: With the 1.1 update adding Essence as a currency for the Vaults, the procedure should remain largely the same. Just replace the spawnitem command with this one:

```
/spawnitem essence x
```

`essence` is the name for Essence in the code. Once again, replace `x` with the amount you want.

Comment: Appreciate for an answer. This one fits asked question better.

Answer (score 2):

An easier way would be to make an Extractor and spawn in Solarium Stars. These give a ton of pixels when broken down.

You can merely use `/admin` and craft your way to the top tiers, then use the [Atomic Furnance](http://starbounder.org/Crafting_Station#Atomic_Furnace) (the maximum level forge) to mass-produce [Solarium Stars](http://starbounder.org/Solarium_Star), then place a [Refinery](http://starbounder.org/Refinery) and force-feed the Solarium into pixels.

Comment: Please guide a bit more, in refference to your answer.

Comment: You can merely use `/admin` and craft your way to the top tiers, then use the maxed forge (Magnetic Crucible, I think) to mass-produce Solarium Stars, then place a Refinery and force-feed the Solarium into pixels.

Comment: Thx. Very usefull hint!

Answer (score 1):

[StarReader](http://c4isbad.com/starreader/) is an editor where you can change any value of your Character wich means you can also change the amount of Pixels you have

Comment: Where i can find a save file? I've a single character and many files at `Steam\SteamApps\common\Starbound\giraffe_storage\player`

Comment: All works. Additional. **(1)** Used `<c>\<program_fils>\Steam\SteamApps\common\Starbound\giraffe_storage\player` in order to find player save. **(2)** Player save file will have `.player` at the end.